# Исправление лексических ошибок (1)

Tags: лексика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Исправьте, пожалуйста, предложения, устраняя лексические ошибки.
Укажите ***разновидности ошибок*:**
выбор слова без учёта его значения;
речевая избыточность (тавтология или плеоназм);
нарушение лексической сочетаемости;
неверное использование паронимов, синонимов, антонимов.

1. Это памятливое событие подсудимый решил отметить на широкую ногу.
2. История появления на месте преступления Григорьева окутана кромешней 
   тайной.
3. Этот молодой участковый сумел сыскать доверие у горожан.
4. В результате операции в руки работников милиции попал целый арсенал оружия.
5. Голодовка поможет вашему организму вывести вредные шлаки, 
   накопившиеся в нем из-за плохого питания.
6. Из-за неэффективного управления деньги налогоплательщиков выпускаются в трубу.
7. Украденную бытовую технику сбывали по супердешевым ценам на Центральном рынке.
8. Ямов ударил меня в область лица, в район правого уха.
9. В нагрудном кармане его брюк было обнаружено две фотографии.
10. Совершение преступления стало возможным благодаря тому, что здание фабрики почти не охраняется.

Comment: @Екатерина2093, Предложите, пожалуйста, свой вариант ответа на данное задание.

Answer (score 2):

1. Это памятное событие подсудимый решил отметить на широкую ногу (неверное использование паронима).
2. История появления на месте преступления Григорьева покрыта тайной (нарушение лексической сочетаемости).
3. Этот молодой участковый сумел снискать доверие у горожан (неверное использование паронима).
4. В результате операции работники милиции обнаружили целый арсенал оружия (выбор слова без учета его значения).
5. Голодание поможет вашему организму вывести вредные шлаки, накопившиеся в нем из-за плохого питания (неверное использование паронима).
6. Из-за неэффективного управления деньги налогоплательщиков вылетают в трубу (выбор слова без учета его значения).
7. Украденную бытовую технику продавали по супердешевым ценам на Центральном рынке (тавтология).
8. Ямов ударил меня в лицо, точнее, в правое ухо (речевая избыточность).
9. В переднем кармане его брюк было обнаружено две фотографии (выбор слова без учета его значения).
10. Совершение преступления стало возможным потому, что здание фабрики почти не охраняется (выбор слова без учета его значения).

Как-то так.